WSL2/Ubuntu Jupyter lab stops mount my windows folders
I'm struggeling with wierd issue. I don't know what I did, but after sometime my jypiter labd notebook stops mounting my windows environment. I now can only see a Ubuntu env, but compleetly lost access to the Windows env. I  have a feeling that there are should be 2 possible troubleshooting solution 1st check environment vars 2nd, check jupyter config. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with any of them. One thing I have to mention tho, I think that i messed up with this line typed in bash:
TENSORRT_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import tensorrt;print(tensorrt.__file__)")) 

now everytime i run
conda activate my_env

I got follwoing message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorrt'
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.

I checked bashrc, nothing in there, tried to reboot wsl no luck. I just can't understand where this line of code is sitting now.
Appreciate your help in advance,
Best regards,
Maks.

Partially solved issue by running following command in PS prior running WSL set WSLENV=C:\Users\NoName. However issue with Traceback message still actual

2nd issue solved by installing TensorRT. Compleete instructions here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing.
